# Can I release iphone app as a fictitious company using a developer account?

Tags: iphone

Or do I need to change to a business account and set up a DBA / LLC?

Comment: I've never heard of such a requirement. If you've seen something that makes it seem that way, can you post a link to it?

Comment: In the signup form I remember seeing that for a business account you need to show proof of an actual business. I haven't actually signed up though (yet), so I don't know the details of what name you can list things under.

Comment: Why not release an iphone app as an individual developer?

Comment: they require a proof of existance from the state you registered your business name. if you are selling as a single individual you have to use your name. if you want to use a business name you have to prove to Apple you own the business, and rightly so.

Comment: the problem is Apple no longer accepts DBAs (which are cheap). I confirmed this over the phone with developer support. That means I need to get an LLC, which will cost about $1200 with all fees in CA. Ugh.

Comment: no you can just incorporate in any state, you don't have to live in the state you incorporate, Delaware is very popular place to incorporate. In GA it is only $99 and you can file online and get it all done in a day.

Comment: This is a business issue, and isn't programming related, so I don't think it's appropriate for Stack Overflow.  You might try the iPhoneSB mailing list instead: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb/

Comment: Oh.... Why iPhone fails so hard, in so few words.

Comment: In Russia, iPhone app develops you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I once talked (Sep 2011) Apple about it and they said no. They do not accept fictitious (doing-as-business) company names. You either have to release it under your real name or need to incorporate.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to be a registered business to sell on the app store. Apple will handle all of the taxation issues for you based on your country of origin. It's pretty straight forward for those of us who don't want to go through the hassle of registering as a business only to sell a $0.99 app.

Comment: if you sell as a business it has to be a business name you own, if you sell as a person your name is the name that the app is sold under.

Comment: Absolutely. I think someone would have a problem if I sold my app under the name "Google" :)